# What type do I cast a CSV json string to its java memeber

Tags: java, android, json, getter-setter

I have a json object I want to case into a java class, I'm not sure what i'm supposed to cast two of the properties to, they are comma seperated strings. The json object looks like this

```
{"color":null,"display_name":null,"id":321,"option_codes":"MS01,RENA,TM00,DRLH,PF00,BT85,PBCW,RFPO,WT19,IBMB,IDPB,TR00,SU01,SC01,TP01,AU01,CH00,HP00,PA00,PS00,AD02,X020,X025,X001,X003,X007,X011,X013","user_id":123,"vehicle_id":1234567890,"vin":"5YJSA1CN5CFP01657","tokens":["x","x"],"state":"online"}
```

The option codes and tokens are the member properties I keep getting an error with this java class.

```
public class Vehicle{
private String color,displayName,vin,state;
private int id,user_id,vehicle_id;
private List<String> option_codes,tokens;
public String getColor() {
    return color;
}
public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}
public String getDisplayName() {
    return displayName;
}
public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
    this.displayName = displayName;
}
public String getVin() {
    return vin;
}
public void setVin(String vin) {
    this.vin = vin;
}
public String getState() {
    return state;
}
public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public int getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}
public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}
public int getVehicle_id() {
    return vehicle_id;
}
public void setVehicle_id(int vehicle_id) {
    this.vehicle_id = vehicle_id;
}
public List<String> getOption_codes() {
    return option_codes;
}
public void setOption_codes(List<String> option_codes) {
    this.option_codes = option_codes;
}
public List<String> getTokens() {
    return tokens;
}
public void setTokens(List<String> tokens) {
    this.tokens = tokens;
}
```

}

Is there a way to cast the option_codes into an array somehow from the csv string?

Comment: you could split it on the ','. But a direct cast to array is not poosible because this is no array

Comment: Kinda what I was thinking, I just have to convert the string manually??

Comment: Yes I think you do have to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setter can do the work for making the list from the string:

```
public void setOption_codes(String option_codes) {
  this.option_codes = Splitter.on(',').splitToList(option_codes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate space in your Vehicle class for the lists:

```
private List<String> option_codes = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
```

It is the problem to convert your string to valid JSON object. so you need to have array begin and end characters as []. Then you need to use google-gson library to convert your Json to an object:

```
        String str = "{\"color\":null,\"display_name\":null,\"id\":321,\"option_codes\":[MS01,RENA,TM00,DRLH,PF00,BT85,PBCW,RFPO,WT19,IBMB,IDPB,TR00,SU01,SC01,TP01,AU01,CH00,HP00,PA00,PS00,AD02,X020,X025,X001,X003,X007,X011,X013],\"user_id\":123,\"vehicle_id\":1234567890,\"vin\":\"5YJSA1CN5CFP01657\",\"tokens\":[\"x\",\"x\"],\"state\":\"online\"}"; //your JSON string;
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Vehicle obj;
        try {
            obj = gson.fromJson(str, Vehicle.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

please take a look at https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @JsonDeserialize and @JsonSerialize annotations. Implement appropriate classes that convert String into List and vise versa. So in your class there will be List, and comma separated string in the json.